# Create trading chart from Bloomberg historical data

Tags: plotting, finance

I am using *Mathematica* 9 with the *Finance Platform*, and have pulled historical data for the Bloomberg Commodity Total Return Index using the following code.

```
bcom := MarketDataGet["Historical", "Instruments" -> {"BCOMTR Index"},
    "Fields" -> {"Last_Price"}, "DateRange" -> {{2012, 1, 1}, {2015, 5, 13}}];
```

How do I then use this data to create a `TradingChart`?  I'm getting the following error:

> First::first: {} has a length of zero and no first element. >>

Alternatively, I have tried a `DateListPlot` with the following error:

> DateListPlot::ntdt: The first argument to DateListPlot should be a list of pairs of dates and real values, a list of real values, or a list of several such lists. >>

Comment: Rob, It seems that nothing is being pulled in from `MarketDataGet`, or that the `:=` (`SetDelayed`) is getting in your way. I am not sure why you would need that, so I would try to use a simple `=` in your assignment of `bcom`. Also, could you add the code with which you tried to get the plots as well?

Comment: @MarcoB  I am getting data pulled in from Bloomberg as I can see it with `Grid[bcom]`.  Also I did try using `bcom=` instead of `bcom:=`.  This may have more to do with the charting functions looking for date/price pairs while the data pulled down includes "BCOMTR Index" in the first column.

Comment: OK good. if you don't particularly need the SetDelayed, I would probably use the regular `=`, just to make things simpler. Add the code you used to attempt plotting that gave you those errors.

Comment: `TradingChart[bcom]` or `DateListPlot[bcom]`

Comment: Alright, one more thing I can suggest: perusing some documentation seems to indicate that the correct format for the Bloomberg last price field should be uppercase `"LAST_PRICE"`. I'm not even sure if that makes a difference, since you say that some data is being pulled in already. Otherwise, examples in the docs similar to your code seem to work more or less as you were expecting. Unfortunately I don't have the Finance Platform, not a Bloomberg subscription to test further...